# What is the German equivalent of "make a difference"?

Tags: english-to-german, idiom, phrase-request

I am looking for the German equivalent of the phrase "make a difference", like in the sentence "In my job, I want to do something that really makes a difference".

Would "etwas zu bewegen" be a good choice?

Comment: "etwas bewegen" can definitely be a suitable choice in many contexts, although it is slightly more specific than "to make a difference".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another alternative could be:

> etwas bewirken

As for example [in](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=COM:2004:0101:FIN:DE:PDF):

> Ein Bereich, in dem der
>   EU-Haushalt **etwas bewirken** kann und sollte, ist ganz klar Forschung und Technologie.

[Translation](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=COM:2004:0101:FIN:EN:PDF):

> An obvious
>   area where the EU budget can, and should, **make a difference** is research and technology.

http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=%22etwas+bewirken%22

Answer (score 6):

Your proposal is indeed a good choice (*»Ich will etwas bewegen«*). Alternatively you could use:

> Ich will die Welt [ein bisschen] besser machen / verbessern.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative translation would be

> einen Wandel herbeiführen

if you want to stick with as much as possible German equivalent of the *make a difference*.

Comment: I would say that "etwas bewirken" is closer to "to make a difference" than "einen Wandel herbeiführen". "To make a difference" means that you want to change something, even if it is not much; "Einen Wandel herbeiführen" to me means to bring about a major change.